# Finding a point on a circle

Tags: circles

I have a circle that I am trying to find series of points on.  I know the radius and horizontal tangent point at the top of the circle.  I need to find a point that lies on the circle's circumference that is $x$ distance below the top point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical coordinate of that point will obviously be $Y=R-x$, where $R$ is the radius. The horizontal one follows from Pythagoras as $X=\sqrt{R^2-(R-x)^2} = \sqrt{2Rx - x^2}$. I don't see where you need this tangent for? Or is this by construction?

Comment: I am trying to write a program that fills a circle with horizontal lines at an even distance.  The lines start at the top of the circle and continue down.  I know the point that is in the middle of the circle and at the very top.  I need to calculate the points on the circumference every second x points down from that point.

Comment: Your equation solved my problem.  It took a little bit for me to realize that I needed to use the negative of that equation to solved for the points on the right side of the triangle though.

Comment: I meant circle, not triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation of the circle be $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

So, the  horizontal tangent point at the top of the circle will be $(h,k+r)$

So, we know $h,k,r$

Any point $(P)$ on the circle  can be $(h+r\cos\theta,k+r\sin\theta)$

So, $(h+r\cos\theta-0)^2+\{k+r\sin\theta-(k+r)\}=x^2$

So, we need to find $\theta$

Comment: I thought of r*cos(theta) and r*sin(theta) immediately, but I cannot work with angles - see my comment to @Lucozade.